# Usage of "as such"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I read that the following is ungrammatical:

> Because of the accident, he arrived at the dock an hour late. As such, he missed the boat and forfeited his deposit.

Why? What is the correct usage of *as such*?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: Did you look up [as such](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such?q=as+such#such__9) and how it's used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such?q=as+such#such__9) has this example:

> **as such**
>
> *[often with negative]* in the exact sense of the word:
> *it is possible to stay overnight here although there is no guest house as such*

That is, while there isn't anything which might be called a guest house, you could find digs in someone's spare bedroom.

There is a more colloquial use of the phrase, too:

> This jersey is too small. As such, it's useless.

That makes use of the main sense of [*such*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/such):

> **such** *determiner, predeterminer, & pronoun*
>
> **1** of the type previously mentioned:
> [as predeterminer]:
> *I longed to find a kindred spirit, and in him I thought I had found such a person*
> *we were second-class citizens and they treated us as such*

That is, “I thought I had found a person who would be a kindred spirit”; “We were second-class citizens and they treated us as second-class citizens.” This is similar to my jersey example: “This jersey is too small. Such a jersey is useless.”

Now, your example “He arrived late. As such, he missed the boat” **doesn’t fit** those forms. You can’t substitute *as such* with either *“in the exact sense of the word”* or repeat the relevant noun phrase, because you don’t have a noun phrase.

Your example, while a common construction which is gaining traction, **is** incorrect. You need a **conjunction** like *Because of this* or even a simple *So*:

> Because of the accident, he arrived at the dock an hour late. So he missed the boat and forfeited his deposit.

Answer (score -1):

Such - is commonly used when we tend to compare things or situations. For example, Such a weather is uncomfortable. In the mentioned sentence, I have compared multiple weather conditions though not mentioned the other conditions.
Or another example Would you like to have tea, coffee or any such thing ?

Now when we use as with such, we give more emphasis on such. Just as we use 'as good' or 'as bad'.